# File with no name or size in fineuploader

Tags: android, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader within a mobile website.

All is working fine except in android`2.3 (Gingerbread)`.

If you open an input dialog and close it without selecting a file, A file is created with no name or size. I cannot use the minFileSize validation check as this is not supported on Gingerbread (2.3).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.3.x fires the change event on a file input element even if the file dialog is dismissed without selecting a file.  In this case, the value of the input element is an empty string.  We should probably work around this by ignoring all change events associated with non File API browsers that contains an empty string for the file input value.

#### Workaround

The workaround is simple but a bit kludgey.  This will no longer be necessary once Fine Uploader has been patched to work around this issue internally.  Until then...

Contribute a [validate event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#validate):

```js
$("#uploader").fineUploader().on("validate", function(event, fileOrBlobData) {
    return fileOrBlobData.name.length > 0 && fileOrBlobData.name !== "qqfile";
});
```

Or for non-jQuery setups...

```js
callbacks: {
    onValidate: function(fileOrBlobData) {
        return fileOrBlobData.name.length > 0 && fileOrBlobData.name !== "qqfile";
    }
}
```

The above code will reject any file with an empty name.  See [Fine Uploader issue #998](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/998) for more details on this issue, and to follow progress on a patch, which will likely be part of 3.9.1.

Comment: Since the workaround is simple, and the issue itself is fairly tame, I'm thinking this will be part of the next major release, 4.0, instead.